# Restore Yardi backup (.bak) files to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, database-restore

I have a SQL Server 2022 Developer instance that I believe will be higher than the Yardi one. I have extracted it using Litespeed into 13 different files as suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/yardi/comments/mpbxwa/not_able_to_restore_backups_from_yardi_database/?onboarding_redirect=%2Fr%2Fyardi%2Fcomments%2Fmpbxwa%2Fnot_able_to_restore_backups_from_yardi_database%2F)  but I get
"The file ID 1 on device is incorrectly formed and can not be read"
when I run the Restore Database with replace, no recovery query.
The BackupName = *** INCOMPLETE ***, Position = 1 and other fields are NULLs when I run the Restore Headeronly query.
Any help will be appreciated.
Many thanks for your anticipated help.

I tried restoring using SSMS and I'm expecting the restore to work and create a database with the data in the backup files.

Comment: This looks like a question for [dba.se], not here on [so].

Comment: `Yardi`??? What's that, except a property management ISV?

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you trying to restore backups created by Yardi DBAs or restore your local backups to a SQL Server hosted on Yardi? Does Yardi use Litespeed? New SQL Server versions *can* restore older backup versions, so if you're trying to restore SQL Server backup files from Yardi on a more recent version, it should work. I don't know if Litespeed's file format is compatible with SQL Server backup though. If not, you need Litespeed itself to restore backups generated with it

Comment: doesn't sound like you extracted them correctly. how does the file names look?

Comment: `...and other fields are NULLs when I run the Restore Headeronly query` it seems this backup isn't a SQL Server backup. The Reddit thread mentions the backups were *compressed using Litespeed*, something SQL Server knows nothing about. Despite the thread's claims though, LiteSpeed isn't free at all. It's actually a `Request Pricing` product. Typically this means expensive contracts instead of one-of purchases. You can download a 15-day trial to see if it can actually read those backup files.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for your comments. Yes, Litespeed is available to current Yardi clients and I was able to download that and extract the backup file from a .bak to 12 .bak files.

Comment: @siggemannen, the 13 file once extracted have 13 different file extensions - from .bak0, .bak1, .bak2 till .bak12. How will you suggest I extract them please?

Comment: hmm, strange, i wonder if the files are zipped or something too

Comment: are you sure you're not compressing .bak files *to* litespeed

Comment: @siggemannen I think the original file was zipped and the Litespeed extractor tool extracted but I doubt if the extracted files were zipped as well... I'd try running the tool on individual files to see if it makes any difference. Thanks

Comment: @siggemannen, nah, one file from the sftp becomes 13 files - I reckon that is what extract means right?

Comment: can you open the .bak0 file with 7zip or something?

Comment: Thanks @siggemannen for all your help. I eventually got it to work. It was a storage issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extracted file size was about 4 times the compressed file. The storage space I had in my drive was not enough so I had to increase it. Thanks All!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).